# Run componentDidMount after a component attribute value change

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-lifecycle

I don't know whether this is possible in React or not as I am a novice React developer. What I want is to call a function when the attribute (data-link) of my input element changes. I use componentDidUpdate but it triggers whenever any component changes.

I just want to call componentDidUpdate whenever there is any change in the specific attribute of a specific element.

Comment: so basically you can set a state within your component that will change when the there is any change in the specific attribute of a specific element, and within the componentDidUpdate you check the status if this state so for example if it is false that means that the change was done ion another element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best option is to check if the specific value is changed __(the one you want to call the function on change), you can use

`if (prevState.attribute !== this.state.attribute) {()=>callFunction}`

then the callFunction is only called when there is a change in the attribute state.